# Unreachable Statement Error Message

Tags: java, bluej

I am making a simple program. When I compile it, BlueJ says "unreachable statement" and highlights "System.out.println(mystery("DELIVER"));". I'm unsure what to do. I would like it to complete the println statement and run it in a main method, but it gives me the same error.

```
public class Test7
{
    public String mystery(String s)
    {
        String s1= s.substring(0,1);
        String s2= s.substring(1, s.length()-1);
        String s3= s.substring(s.length()-1);

        if (s.length() <= 3)
            return s3 + s2 + s1;
        else 
            return s1 + mystery(s2) + s3;
        System.out.println(mystery("DELIVER"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether the `if`-statement is `true` or `false`, you return, so the `println` statement cannot be reached.

Maybe that became clearer once I corrected your bad indentations.

Cannot answer what you should do, since you haven't declared your intention. Did you intend the `println` statement to be in a separate `main` method, perhaps?

Comment: Sorry I copy and pasted my program, so my indentations were off. I tried putting the println statement in a main method, but it gave me the same error.

Comment: @TheUnicornMaster that's not true, if you put the print statment alone in a main method, it can't give you the same error. 

What the error is saying is that the line of code will never be executed because either the if or else will always be executed. That's what Andrreas has explained in his answer. If you specify what you want to achieve, I can help further.

Comment: Well, I answered why *this* code is giving the error. Accept this answer or delete the question, then post a new question with the other code.